# How to use a static array as class property in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a following property in MyClass2:

```
 Private MyClass1Array(1 To 4) As MyClass1
```

where MyClass1 is another class I have defined. I don't know how to adress this property: it can't be set public, so I wrote this in MyClass2 module:

```
Public Property Let SetMyClass1Array(i As Integer, c As MyClass1)
    MyClass1Array(i) = c
End Property

Public Property Get GetMyClass1Array(i As Integer) As MyClass1
    GetMyClass1Array = MyClass1Array(i)
End Property
```

But this also doesn't work. How to write this properties correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you work with Class-objects, you need to use `Set` as you handle object-references, not primitive data-type values.

```
Public Property Let SetMyClass1Array(i As Integer, c As MyClass1)
    Set MyClass1Array(i) = c
End Property

Public Property Get GetMyClass1Array(i As Integer) As MyClass1
    Set GetMyClass1Array = MyClass1Array(i)
End Property
```

Comment: +1 there is also `property set` instead of `let` to allow `set x.SetMyClass1Array(a) = b`